# Case statement for multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table "financials" like:

```
CODE  NAME  ACTUAL
26    xxx   7654
54    yyy   8543
3     zzz   1873
7     aaa   6543
16    bbb   0321
```

Im creating a new view "actual" derived from previous table which should look like :

```
invoice_sales    no_of_customer    currency    source_orig          name
7654                0                 USD        MSMDS_FINANCIALS   xxx
8543                0                 USD        MSMDS_FINANCIALS   yyy
0                 1873                USD        MSMDS_FINANCIALS   zzz
0                 6543                USD        MSMDS_FINANCIALS   aaa
0321                0                 USD        MSMDS_FINANCIALS   bbb
```

I have written the below code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW actual
AS
SELECT
CASE WHEN Code IN ('16','26','54') THEN actual AS invoice_sales and 0 AS no_of_customer 
ELSE WHEN Code IN ('3','7') THEN 0 AS invoice_sales and actual AS no_of_customer END
,'USD' AS currency
,'MSMDS_FINANCIALS' AS source_orig
,name
FROM
financials
```

But getting the error below:

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input 'Code' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}

== SQL ==
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW actual
AS
SELECT
CASE WHEN Code IN ('16','26','54') THEN actual AS invoice_sales and 0 AS no_of_customer 
ELSE WHEN Code IN ('3','7') THEN 0 AS invoice_sales and actual AS no_of_customer END
-----------^^^
,'USD' AS currency
,'MSMDS_FINANCIALS' AS source_orig
,name
FROM
financials
```

Any suggestion or help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `case` expression returns a *single* value ("scalar value" in SQL-speak).  So, you need to repeat the `case` for each column:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Code IN ('16', '26', '54') THEN actual 
             WHEN Code IN ('3', '7') THEN 0
        END) AS invoice_sales 
       (CASE WHEN Code IN ('16', '26', '54') THEN 0 
             WHEN Code IN ('3', '7') THEN actual
        END) AS no_of_customer, 
      'USD' AS currency
      'MSMDS_FINANCIALS' AS source_orig,
      name
FROM financials
```